# Xcode breakpoint ignore x times - does not work

Tags: debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

I'm using Xcode 4.0.2 for an iOS project and have problems with the breakpoint option (right/control-click) "ignore x times before stopping". When i set x to 0, it stops everytime and that's ok. But with x set to anything greater 0 it ignores the breakpoint although the line of code is executed. It should run x times over the breakpoint and stop when executing the line for the x+1 time. 
How can i get this to work?

Comment: It looks like this is only an issue with the simulator. When i debug it on the real device it works and regards the "ignore x times before stopping" settings.